# Coded UI Tests: Start application under test only if it is not already running

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

When using "Coded UI tests" in Visual Studio 2010, is there an easy way to start the application under test (AUT) **only if the AUT is not already running**?

I know that I can implement such a piece of startup code from scratch, but I wonder whether the Visual Studio test framework offers something out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems as if this can be done using this code:

```cs
[TestInitialize]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    if (_application != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ApplicationUnderTest");
    if (processes.Length > 0)
    {
        _application = ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess(processes[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        _application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Path\To\ApplicationUnderTest.exe");
    }
}
```

The AUT is launched only if it is not already running.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in method to start an application if it isn't currently running that I am aware of.

It would be trivial to write something custom to do this just be sure that you are able to get your application under test into a known state so a previous test failure doesn't cause all tests run after it to fail. For web applications getting to a known state is likely as a simple as setting the URL but for complicated desktop applications it could be exceptionally complicated to get back to a known state.